# How to add lifetime to object in a Vec<Box<_>> owned by Self?

Tags: rust

How do I go about making it clear to the compiler that `World` will own `system` and that their lifetimes are similar?

```
trait System {
    fn process(&self);
}

struct Action {
    who: i32,
}
impl System for Action {
    fn process(&self) {
        println!("id: {}", self.who);
    }
}

type SystemVec = Vec<Box<System>>;
struct World {
    systems: SystemVec,
}
impl World {
    fn new() -> Self {
        World {
            systems: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_system<S: System>(&mut self, system: S) {
        self.systems.push(Box::new(system));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = World::new();
    w.add_system(Action { who: 0 });
}
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `S` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:27
   |
26 |         self.systems.push(Box::new(system));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `S: 'static`...
note: ...so that the type `S` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:26:27
   |
26 |         self.systems.push(Box::new(system));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Did you do as the compiler suggests: *consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `S: 'static` so that the type `S` will meet its required lifetime bounds*?

Comment: yes, and I tried adding a lifetype, couldn't find a way to add it. And just 'S: 'static` doesn't help me in actually adding it.

Comment: *doesn't help me in actually adding it* — [seems to work for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3890cb86f1c1ee0e15165609a25a3503&version=stable).

Comment: What you have in your link *does* help. Part of my problem is not knowing the synatx

Comment: Seriously, I encourage you to file an issue (or find an existing one) at the [Rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust). Rust always wants to make error messages better — if this wasn't clear enough, it can probably be improved.